# How to change State immutably React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, immutability

How do I change the contents of the state without changing all the data in the state.

for context;

The function below runs inside another "handleChange" function that accepts the event and assigns the various data in "event.target"  to the variables name, pos and value. The update function creates and returns an object with arrays. I use the object to update the state. Every time there is an onchange event that calls the overall function, the state only shows the current onchange data not the data from the previous inputs that have already undergone "a change"(am hoping you understand what I mean here)

further clarification;

I am trying to update the state each time using an "onChange" event handler in the input. I change the values of an unput, it reflects the changes in the state (it console logs out the changes perfectly),however as soon as I change the values of another input, the previous changes in the state disappears.

I would like to change the values of the input, have that value stored in the state, change another input have that value also stored in the object of arrays ..etc, then be able to access all the values. I am now only able to access the latest

```
  handleInputChange(e) {
if (e.target.value) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formDataArray = {
    code: [],
    desc: [],
    qty: [],
    prices: [],
    line_price: []
  };

  let update = function(value, pos, name) {
    switch (name) {
      case "description":
        formDataArray.desc[pos - 1] = value;

        break;
      case "code":
        formDataArray.code[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "qty":
        formDataArray.qty[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "price":
        formDataArray.prices[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "line_price":
        formDataArray.line_price[pos - 1] = value;

        break;
      default:
    }
    return formDataArray;
  };

  var valuesTwo = e.target.name.split("-");

  var name = valuesTwo[1];
  var value = e.target.value;
  var pos = valuesTwo[0];

  //  update(value, pos, name);
  //  update(value, pos, name);
  this.setState({ formData: update(value, pos, name) });
}
```

}

result of update function

```
{code: Array(0), desc: Array(1), qty: Array(0), prices: Array(0), line_price: Array(0)}
code
:
[]
desc
:
["test"]
line_price
:
[]
prices
:
[]
qty
:
[]
__proto__
:
Object
```

when I change the values of a different input

```
{code: Array(0), desc: Array(2), qty: Array(0), prices: Array(0), line_price: Array(0)}
code
:
[]
desc
:
(2) [empty, "another test"]
line_price
:
[]
prices
:
[]
qty
:
[]
__proto__
:
Object
```

The part where it says empty I would like to persist the previous data "test"

This is how the Inputs are generated; It is a grid system. There are five inputs(think of them as a row), when a user clicks a button another row is generated(row 2), when another button is clicked, row 3 is generated. The input fields are for example (2-description).
I would like to save it as an array grid of some sort to perform some functionality for example add an entire column as a user enters the fields for example the price.

```
 triggerRows() {
        this.setState({
          invoiceRows: this.state.invoiceRows + 1,
          viewSubmitButton: true
        });
      }

  dynamicRows() {
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < this.state.invoiceRows; i++) {
      items.push(
        <div>
          <input
            onClick={this.triggerRows}
            type="text"
            name={i + "-code"}
            defaultValue="code"
            key={i}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name={i + "-description"}
            defaultValue="description"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name={i + "-qty"}
            defaultValue="qty"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name={i + "-price"}
            defaultValue="price"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name={i + "-line_price"}
            defaultValue="line Price"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <br />
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean you are not getting updated `formData` in console `  console.log(this.state.formData);` ?

Comment: How is the shape of your state? Is formData object of arrays?

Comment: you mean that `console.log(this.state.formData);` not showing the changed values?

Comment: @devserkan formData is an object of arrays. I am trying to update the state each time using an "onChange" event handler in the input. I change the values of an unput, it reflects the changes in the state, as soon as I change the values of another input, the previous changes in the state disappears

Comment: Here, you are overriding whole formData, so it is normal to lose the previous state. @fejanto's answer should do the trick.

Comment: So, you are returning formData again. This means you don't need old state of formData. You are replacing it again. Maybe your whole code will help to whom want to help. Your inputs etc. Using a function, changing some properties then returning a whole object, after that setting this as state is not so optimal I think. There are better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
var valuesTwo = e.target.name.split("-");

        var name = valuesTwo[1];
        var value = e.target.value;
        var pos = valuesTwo[0];

        //  update(value, pos, name);
        this.setState(state => ({
            formData: {...state.formData, ...update(value, pos, name)}
        }), () => console.log(this.state.formData));
```

Comment: it did not, am still getting only the values of the latest input I changed, as soon as I change another input, I only get the latest value.

Comment: This answer should solve your problem, this is why I upvoted it. It keeps the previous state of formData and add new values to it without mutating the state directly. If not try to debug other parts of your code.

Comment: @devserkan I see, I  will debug, I have added the entire code block, help me see what could be wrong.

Comment: thank you for your input @fejanto Your code works with a different data set, what am trying to store is an object of arrays.

Comment: Can you add your formData shape and result of update function in your question?

Comment: @devserkan I have added some more detail, hope it is enough

Comment: For me, it is still not clear. How do you get values, position information from your form. How is your inputs' shape in that form?

Comment: @David Mbwana could you add the formData shape/structure to the question so I can see where you want to get?

Comment: @fejanto and devserkan thanks for sticking around, I have tried explaining the structure as best as I can. It is basically a grid of five inputs(rows) generated dynamically. They all utilize the same "onchange" event Listener. I am aiming for the result; as the user fills in the form the data gets stored in the state in a neat order(the object of arrays).

Comment: Your logic is either too complex for me or you are overthinking. A bunch of dynamic inputs, add and change values at the same time, do this with arrays. Without submit and a separate state for handleChange, I can't think any better and optimum way to change the state with your code. Maybe starting over, thinking simpler may help you. By the way, I'm not an experienced developer. There might be someone else who can show you the right way. Handling inputs and forms is not hard with React but not like this.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` works as `async` so In order to see change in console after updating a state put `console.log` inside `callback` function of state.

```
 this.setState({
     ...this.state,
     formData: update(value, pos, name)
 }, () => console.log(this.state.formData));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you pass an object to  [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), it will perform a **merge**

So `this.setState({formData: update(value, pos, name)});` will just update the `formData` property

By the way `setState` is **asynchronous**, then `console.log(this.state.formData);` will not write the updated value, instead you can pass a callback to `setState`

```
this.setState(
    {formData: update(value, pos, name)},
    () => console.log(this.state.formData)
);
```